# Combinatorics question: Lexicographic Topological sort of De Bruijn sequence after removing edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am self-learning an Algorithms course with a friend, and we are struggling to understand the answer to a question we were trying to solve for a couple of days. The question slightly involves a De Bruijn sequence, which I will explain at the bottom of the post what it is as it's not too well-known. The main part we don't understand is specifically combinatorics, however.

**QUESTION**:

Given a De Bruijn graph, prove that it is sufficient to remove $\frac{k^n+k}{2}$ edges to produce a topological sort of the graph which is also in lexicographical order.

**Our partial answer:**

First, we wish to remove all self-loops, as topological sort does not allow cycles; In any such graph there would be $k$ such edges (words containing only a single type of letter, e.g 11111 or 00000).

After this, we would wish to remove any edge which connects a vertex to a vertex which precedes it in lexicographical order. Unfortunately, this is where we are stuck; we weren't able to figure out how to calculate how many such edges exist. After eventually looking at the answers, apparently the answer is "exactly half of the remaining edges" ($\frac{k^n-k}{2}$) which, when we add to it the $k$ edges we removed earlier, arrives at the previous answer.

Now, while I recognize that usually dividing by two in combinatorics is due to duplicates of some sort, which implies symmetry, we still can't figure out the mathematical explanation for how/why the number of edges in a De Bruijn graph which break topological+lexicographical sort is exactly half. If anyone can explain how this comes about, I would highly appreciate it!

---

**DE BRUIJN EXPLANATION**:

For a given alphabet of $k$ letters and a word length of $n$, there are $k^n$ possible word combinations; a De Bruijn graph is, essentially, a directed connected graph from which all of these possible words in this language can be made: each edge is a 'word' in this language (word of length n made of k letters), and the vertices are all of the words of length $n-1$, so $k^{n-1}$ vertices in total. These graphs can be used to make a "De Bruijn Sequence", which is a cyclic string of letters from which all words of the above mentioned $k$, $n$ can be made, via Euler cycles.

For example, here is a De Bruijn graph and three of its respective sequences (which is really just the same sequence just shifted forwards, as it's cyclic. Note that a De Bruijn graph is not necessarily complete, that's just the case here:

[De Bruijn Graph Illustration, for alphabet {0,1} (k=2),n=2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pCWE.png)

A respective De Bruijn sequence for this graph would be 0110; note that if we copy and shift this cyclic sequence by 1 $k-1$ times, we can quickly get all the possible words, and that a sequence is of length $k^n$:

0110
0011

that is, note the columns of this form all the possible words for the given k, n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An edge corresponding to the word $w_1 w_2 \dots w_n$ should be removed if $$w_2 w_3 \dots w_n \preceq w_1 w_2 \dots w_{n-1},$$ where $\preceq$ denotes the lexicographic order. When does this happen? There are several cases:

- When $w_2 < w_1$.
- When $w_2 = w_1$ and $w_3 < w_2$.
- When $w_2 = w_1$ and $w_3 = w_2$ and $w_4 < w_3$.
- ...
- And so on up until the last case, where $w_1 = w_2 = \dots = w_{n-1}$ and $w_n < w_{n-1}$.
- Wait, no, the *last* last case is loops, which is where $w_1 = w_2 = \dots = w_n$.

How many edges correspond to each case? Let's look at the $i^{\text{th}}$ case, where $w_1 = w_2 = \dots = w_i$, $w_{i+1} < w_i$, and further letters (if they exist) are unconstrained. For $i=1, 2, \dots, n-1$, there are $\binom k2$ ways to choose $w_i$ and $w_{i+1}$. This determines the choice of $w_1, \dots, w_{i-1}$ as well. Then there are $k^{n-i-1}$ ways to choose $w_{i+2}, \dots, w_n$. (The $i=n$ case is loops, which we count separately.)

Altogether, the non-loop cases add up to
$$
   \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \binom k2 k^{n-i-1} = \frac{k(k-1)}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} k^{n-i-1} = \frac{k(k-1)}{2} \left(k^{n-2} + k^{n-3} + \dots + k + 1\right).
$$
By the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series, this simplifies to
$$
   \frac{k(k-1)}{2} \cdot \frac{k^{n-1} - 1}{k-1} = \frac{k(k^{n-1}-1)}{2} = \frac{k^n - k}{2}.
$$
Adding the loops back in, we get $\frac{k^n+k}{2}$ as our final answer.

---

Or, we could count the non-loop cases by the following symmetry argument. All of the non-loop edges we remove can be characterized in the following way: not all of $w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n$ are equal, and at the first position where $w_i \ne w_{i+1}$, we have $w_i > w_{i+1}$.

By symmetry, there is an equal number of edges where not all of $w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n$ are equal, and at the first position where $w_i \ne w_{i+1}$, we have $w_i < w_{i+1}$. Together, these add up to the edges where not all of $w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n$ are equal, and there are $k^n-k$ such edges. Half of these, or $\frac{k^n-k}{2}$, have $w_i > w_{i+1}$ at the first position where $w_i ne w_{i+1}$.